# Remove event handler by guid

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I can get info about all event handlers for an element like this.

```
$._data($('#element_id')[0], "events");
```

This gives me a record for every event handler.

```
0: {type: "change", origType: "change", data: null, guid: 315, handler: ƒ, …}
```

I want to use this guid to remove a specific event handler.

I know that an alternative is to use the name of the callback function or a namespace but this question is about using guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.prototype.unbindByGuid = function (guid) {
    $(this).each(function (index, element) {
        var handlers = [];

        $.each($._data(element, "events"), function (key, value) {
            $.each(value, function (index, value) {
                if(value.guid == guid) handlers.push({eventType: key, handler: value.handler});
            });
        });

        handlers.forEach(function (handler) { $(element).unbind(handler.eventType, handler.handler); });
    });
}
```